# Retrieve contract byte code

Tags: accounts, etherscan, bytecode

How may I find the byte code of an arbitrary contract? Preferably using a website and not writing my own client.

Answer (score 1):

Find an address that actually *is* a contract and view the bytecode like this:

https://etherscan.io/address/0xd26114cd6EE289AccF82350c8d8487fedB8A0C07#code

Note the source code is not there by default, but the bytecode is. In order to get the verified source code, the developer has to complete optional Etherscan verification steps.

Hope it helps.